# AndEngine - Hyperspace type effect

Tags: android, andengine

I'm still learning how to use the excellent AndEngine and I've done some searching, but I cannot find an examples of how to create an effect like jumping to "hyperspace". The effect doesn't have to be as complicated as what would be seen in Star Wars, but could be as simple as the old windows "stars" screen saver. If any of you guru's have ideas or a direction to point me in, that would be great!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USLTQVt8QyA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty easy. Create some stars near the center of the Scene, then use PathModifier to move them. The vector of movement will be the same as the one from the center of the Scene towards the star's original position, except longer. Use ScaleModifier to change the stars' size as they move towards the edges. You will need to make the stars move faster as they approach the edges, for that you can use ease functions which are built-in in AndEngine or you can do the heavy lifting yourself and come up with some equations that will describe the movement of the stars from your point of view.